# Strange gclid parameter in url

Tags: magento-1.9, url

Sometimes i see a strange gclid parameter in our url, for example: https://www.marington.nl/mode/tassen/shop/cognac/leer/?gclid=CI7s-5Xk-csCFVG6Gwod40EGCg.
How is this possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should read this post.

https://www.wordstream.com/gclid

It will help you to track why you are getting this urls

Answer (score 2):

I think you got this url from the google search:

> **Gclid** is a globally unique tracking parameter (Google Click
>   Identifier) used by Google to pass information back and forth between
>   Google AdWords and Google Analytics. If you enable URL auto tagging in
>   Google AdWords, Google will append a unique ?gclid parameter on your
>   destination URLs at run-time. Because it is a redirect, you won't see
>   any gclid parameters on your ad words text ad destination url's, but
>   it will show up in your Web server log files. Auto tagging was
>   introduced in 2004 and is on by default in any Google AdWords
>   accounts.

[Source](https://www.wordstream.com/gclid)

[Additional info](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2938246?hl=en) from the google support.